# Jquery stop function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a jquery function like this:

```
function get()
 {
$.ajax({
     url: 'get.php',
     success: function(data) {
     $('#get').html(data);
     $('#get').fadeIn(2000);
     setTimeout(posts,2000);
    }
    });
 }
 get();
```

I want to stop this function when i click on a certain element in a webpage, how would i do this.

Thanks

Comment: Check this [Abort Ajax requests using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/446594/abort-ajax-requests-using-jquery)

Comment: Do you want to stop the ajax request or the fadeIn-animation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set a variable for your AJAX request.

```
var getajax;

function get() {
    getajax = $.ajax({

     ......
    });
}
```

When you want to abort it, simply

```
getajax.abort();
```

Answer (score 0):

In a situation where you may not be able to globaly define all of your `.ajax()` call variables (as shown by [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11700826/558021) by [@uzyn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/718763/uzyn)), this might be a suitable solution.

You could simply wrap your `success` callback with a flag indicating whether you want to cancel the result.

```
var ajax_canceled = false;

function get(){
  $.ajax({
    url: 'get.php',
    success: function(data) {
      if (!ajax_canceled){
          //...
      }
    }
  });
}
get();

$("#cancel_ajax").on('click',function(){
  ajax_canceled = true;
});
```